# MeshLab 2016 Win 64 won't start or open

Tags: meshlab

After downloading and installing the *MeshLab 2016 Win 64 version* to the default *C:\Program Files\VCG\MeshLab* everything appears to be installed until I try to open the program from either the shortcut or the start menu. Two dialogue boxes flash open and close again before I can read them.

I can't tell if it's an error message or not. When I open the command prompt the only command I know is "start" which seems to open a new command prompt box. Does anyone have a fix for this problem? It would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem initially with W10.

By starting the program by "right click / Execute with the graphics processor / Nvidia" instead of "Intel (default)" the problem disappeared.

Merci à Eric pour m'avoir mis sur la piste...

Answer (score 3):

Do you have an Intel integrated graphic card ? It seems there is a problem with such devices as reported in [issue #29](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/29).